# UITableview No Longer Refreshing in iOS 10 after initial import

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, ios10, reloaddata

I have an application that imports an XML file at first launch to create a table. This worked perfectly fine in iOS 9. In iOS 10, it still imports all the data correctly, and performs the fetch correctly, but the table won't show the items until I force quit the app and open it again. Instead it just shows the first item from the xml file. When I click on the item, it actually takes me to the first item in the ordered list of 298 items (which is a different item).

Link to video showing issue: [reloading table issues](http://www.toycollectorapp.com/ios-10-uitableview-update-issues/)

Order:

- 1) App opens on initial launch, prompts user to "import data". Parser
  is used to import XML and successfully runs through XML (I can print
  a log of each item).
- 2) App saves the importContext and calls
  tableView.reloadData
- 3) At this point, data should be in table.
  Navigation title includes a count, which is correct (298 items).
  However, only 1 item is in the table, the first item from the XML
  file.
- 4) If I click on that item, it takes me to what would be the
  first item in the list of 298 items (NOT the item actually in the
  table).
- 5) Interestingly, if I perform a search, the name of the 1
  item doesn't change, but if I click on it, it takes me to the item I
  searched for. If I search for a different item and click on the 1
  item in the table, it takes me to the new item (but still never
  changes the text of the existing item) - so all 298 items are there,
  just not showing in the table.

I've tried calling

```
self.viewDidLoad
```

and

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

and calling all three above functions using the NSNotificationCenter AFTER the parsing is complete with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performFetch", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.test), name: "performFetch", object: nil)
```

But nothing actually resets the one item in the tableView (which happens to be the first item in the xml file. Again, all the data is there, just invisible.

If I force quit the app and open it back up, all the data is there and visible and works just fine. Is there a different/new way to force a tableview refresh in iOS 10? Again, this feature worked fine in ios 9, no code changed, but in ios 10 it fails. I have not upgraded to Swift 3.0 because it is going to be a pain.

Comment: Having a similar issue with iOS 10.0.2 (it actually started happening with this version), but if I scroll the table, it loads (with some glitches, but it does).

Comment: @dccarmo by glitch do you mean repeating data? thats the issue im dealing with now

Comment: @Multinerd I don't quite remember, but I don't think it was repeating data.

Answer (score 0):

You do your cell configuration in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? I had a similar problem and i solved it moving the code in willDisplayCell:.

Comment: Perhaps you could take the time to post a little example of the code you used, it would improve your answer.